# MapKit delays displaying annotation when dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, mapkit

I'm having an issue returning from a background job to the main thread to make a **UI** update to `MapKit`. The bottom snippet of code is how I'm attempting to return to the main queue to make the update, and while this does work, there is a very large delay (20-35 seconds at least). The top snippet simply removes the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{`

Works perfectly (but blocks)

```
annotation *customAnnotationClass =[[customAnnotationClass alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( [lat doubleValue], [lng doubleValue])];

[annotation createAnnotationView];

    self.myAnnotations=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:annotation, nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_myMapView addAnnotations:_myAnnotations];
    });
}
```

Large delay (10-15 seconds) to actually update annotation onto map.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

annotation *customAnnotationClass =[[customAnnotationClass alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( [lat doubleValue], [lng doubleValue])];

[annotation createAnnotationView];

    self.myAnnotations=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:annotation, nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_myMapView addAnnotations:_myAnnotations];
    });
}
});
```

Any thoughts how I can successfully return to the main thread and make the `UI` update?

Comment: Why have you made this so complex? Is `createAnnotationView` computationally expensive or accessing data from the network?

Comment: Yes, it's fetching a large amount of data to be associated with the annotation. @Paulw11

Comment: Why do you dispatch sync on the main queue instead of Async?

Comment: That was the result of a test...I'm using async. I'll update, but still causing big delays @Paulw11